# She left her iPad behind!

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Our friend returned to the UK on Easy-jet yesterday, but unfortunately left her iPad in our house in France. Naturally she wants us to send it to her, how can we do this to avoid customs duty. It is several years old, but we don't have any paperwork covering it. Can anyone tell us the best way to go about this please?

Comment: I suppose it may depend on the value of the device.  Do you have any idea what that might be?

Comment: Book another EasyJet flight and take it with you?

Comment: Use form: [CN23](https://www.postoffice.co.uk/mail/customs-forms/CN23-form-guide) ; Catagory of Item: **Other:** return of property to owner in the UK

Comment: See also: [How to avoid taxes and fees being levied on gifts sent UK to France](https://www.connexionfrance.com/article/French-news/How-to-avoid-taxes-and-fees-being-levied-on-gifts-sent-UK-to-France): **French parcel post involves several forms** which uses CN23 when sending from a french post office.

Comment: @MarkJohnson is that info not for the reverse direction: KU to France?

Comment: @mdewey Customs forms are the same and the link tells how it must done at a french post office. Look for the bold text.

Comment: @Traveller Tell the friend to book another EasyJet flight to come and collect it.  The OP shouldn't be forced to deal with the hassle of traveling because of someone else's forgetfulness.  And for a fun comparison [Hotel lost my clothes; sent them to my home; now I am being chased to pay for delivery](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/154498/hotel-lost-my-clothes-sent-them-to-my-home-now-i-am-being-chased-to-pay-for-de)

Comment: @mdewey You are still required to fill CN23 when shipping outside of the EU with the French Post